# Prevent accidental use of rm

Tags: linux, security, filesystems, rm

I was going to clean up a directory filled with write protected directories, so I elevated to root, and instead of running rm -rf * / I ran rm -rf /*. You can guess what happened.

Is there a way this could be prevented?

Answer (score 2):

To straighten this up you need to create 2 simple bash scripts and preferably put them in `/usr/local/bin`. I named them `rm.sh` and `sudo.sh`.

Then in your `.bashrc` you add two lines:

```
alias rm='/usr/local/bin/rm.sh'
alias sudo='/usr/local/bin/sudo.sh'
```

`rm.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=`echo $1`
b=`echo $2`
c=`echo "$a" | sed -e 's/^\(.\{1\}\).*/\1/'`
d=`echo "$b" | sed -e 's/^\(.\{1\}\).*/\1/'`

if [ "$c" = "/" ] || [ "$d" = "/" ]; then
    if [ "$c" = "/" ]; then
      echo "You can't erase from $c"
    elif [ "$d" = "/" ]; then
      echo "You can't erase from $d"
fi
    else rm $1 $2
fi

exit 0
```

The script sets 2 variables `a` and `b` where the first is the `rm`-command's first argument - which could be either a file, a directory or flags. The second argument is either a file or a directory.

Variables `c` and `d` are set as the first char of both variables `a` and `b`.

The if-statement tests if either `c` or `d` is eqivalent with `/`. If so, that means the `rm`-command is trying to erase something directly from root which this script prohibits.

Therefore the script echoes "You can't erase from /"

If needed to erase from `/`, then comment away the line in your `.bashrc` and source it again.

If the aliases are set both in your own `.bashrc` as well as a `.bashrc` for root, this will prevent erasing from `/` both for yourself and for the root user.

However, it will not work if the command is invoked with `sudo`. Therefore another script is needed.

`sudo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=`echo $1`

if [ $a = "rm" ]; then
    echo "You can't run the rm command with sudo due to risks for accidental erasure."
else
    sudo $1 $2 $3
fi

exit 0
```

When `sudo` is used this script will be invoked. The only thing it checks is if the first argument is `rm` - and thus forbidding the use of `sudo rm <whatever>`. When doing so, it echoes "You can't run the rm command with sudo due to risks for accidental erasure." If not using `sudo` with the `rm` command, `sudo <command> <arg1> <arg2>` will be accepted.

If needing to erase something with root privileges, then run `sudo su`, erase it as root (though you can't erase from `/`) and exit back to regular user.

Another detail to make this more robust. Add a bogus directory at the absolute top when listing the directories in root.

In many systems it starts with /bin at the top when running ls -la at /.

Create a directory

```
/aaa
```

Then when, as root, running

```
rm -rf *
```

, the script **rm.sh** will be invoked, and since there is no "/" in the arguments, it will be executed.

However only as "**rm $1 $2**".

```
rm -rf * at /
```

will then become unfolded as

```
/aaa /bin /boot (and so on).
```

Then the only directory that actually will be erased is the bogus directory **/aaa** (since that equals $3).

Answer (score 0):

First: Congratulations, you are well on your way in your professional career (This is a thing that happens in Unix because we prefer to trade power for ease of use).

To respond to your question, in the strategic sense: Yes?  In the short term: Maybe?

Short term:

You can totally replace the 'rm' command a wrapper that is more cautious.  I strongly recommend *against* creating your own version of 'sudo' however; use the /etc/sudoers file to configure sudo instead.  It gives you enough control for what you want to do.  It will take a little bit of learning, but it is worth every minute in the long run.  I strongly recommend using sudo over su in general.

Keep in mind that while this is the canonical first major mistake / trigger for an obsession with backups for Unix admins, it is FAR from the only major mistake you can make.  The first other examples I can think of are 'chmod' and 'chown' which are programs that will recursively make your life miserable in a very short period of time.

Fundamentally you want to use sudo not because of the much better auditing that it provides particularly in a multi-user environment, but because it offers the slightest bit of friction for operating with nearly infinite privileges on the system, and the ability to get a shot at filtering (using sudoers) before you do something crazy.

Longer term:

In the strategic sense, you'd probably need to use a shell that either refuses to take wildcards at all (a little difficult to use sometimes), or that is a lot more communicative with you about what you are about to do before it does it.  Sadly, I don't know any of those.

It would be interesting also to have an execution of 'sudo' trigger a filesystem snapshot before running the 'sudo' command.  That wouldn't be perfect, but it could definitely help.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've been looking into this with tweaking /etc/sudoers, but basically for me it falls on allowing a command to be used with elevated privileges when certain arguments are given, bot not when others are given. For instance in this case, how do you allow someone in the /etc/sudoers-file to use rm (and other commands) except when the arguments are "-rf" and you are standing in "/" when executing it? I really want to be able to use "rm -rf" elsewhere in the system - not just when standing in system root.

Comment: My man page for sudoers has an example 'pete HPPA = /usr/bin/passwd [A-Za-z]*, !/usr/bin/passwd *root*' that is closely aligned with filtering the arguments per your question.  The rest of it falls back to the original tradeoff of power vs. ease of use.  Can it be done?  Yes.  For the specific case of rm: It is possible to create a much safer version of rm (e.g. add -Iv to the arguments in GNU coreutils 8.32 to probably catch the problem you hit early).  The challenge is that you're treating a symptom; almost any command run as root can be problematic.

Comment: I understand what you mean. Still there is a difference between problematic and disastrous.

I will later on look into whether it can be done in /etc/sudoers, but for now I'm happy with this arrangement since it provides a new layer of safety that simply wasn't there before.

Comment: For clarity, I often use minimizing language; problematic was a euphemism for disastrous.  Removing the execute bit from every file and directory on your filesystem is disastrous.  You likely would have to do much the same recovery you would have to do if you used rm, as the system would not be bootable, and a backup is your best source of the relevant metadata.